# Adding type and charset in json base64 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I need to change the json body responce:

```
{
    "id": "1581fbd2-c045-4162-9f4c-ddbca6a88d61",
    "content": "//content in base64"
    "title": "ProfileImage",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "created": "2023-08-03T18:55:46.736405+03:00"
}
```

"content" field like this:

```
 "content": "Data: image/jpeg; Charset: utf-8;//content in base64"
```

Is there a way to do it in the mapping config?

Tried adding values directly in the controller

```
 var result = await _mediaService.GetById(id);

            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            string base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(result.Content);
            string metaInfo = string.Format("Data: {0}; Charset: {1}", result.Type, Encoding.UTF8.WebName);
            string base64String = metaInfo + Convert.ToBase64String(result.Content);

            var mapResult = _mapper.Map<MediaModelResponse>(result);

            var response = new
            {
                mapResult.Id,
                Content = base64String,
                mapResult.Title,
                mapResult.Created
            };

            return Ok(response);
```

It works but i want to find a better solution

Also tried to add a new field "ContentTest" to my model and write the result directly

```
mapResult.ContentTest = base64String;
```

Comment: what exactly you don't like about your solution ?

Comment: @Madhatter idk, it seems ok 4 me since im a beginner, but i dont feel it follows coding standarts, the quality is low

Comment: It works, sometimes it's all that matters :) If you start duplicating your code in many places, you could maybe move it inside `_mapper.Map<MediaModelResponse>(result);` method. Is there a reason you don't return `mapResult` object directly and instanciate an anonymous `response` object ?

Comment: @Madhatter actually i have no idea how to move it inside _mapper.Map<MediaModelResponse>(result); since im not that experienced, my supervisor also told me my code is garbage ;)

Comment: Oh. Very charming :) Explicitly type, charset and base64 code ?

Comment: Maybe because you use twice `Convert.ToBase64String(result.Content);` and have no use of variable `base64Data` ?

Comment: @Madhatter yup, actually he mentioned doing this in mapping config, but i have no idea how

Comment: So he wants you to move the code inside `Map<>` method or into a configuration used by `Map<>` method. Seems OK to me ;)

Comment: @Madhatter are there any good examples or what would you suggest to google?

Comment: First things first : what is `_mapper` variable type ? Is this coming from a third party library ?

Comment: @Madhatter  `_mapper` comes from `private IMapper _mapper;(AutoMapper) `
Also the model has settings
`public MediaMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<MediaDto, MediaModelResponse>();
        }`

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your title and question to mention `AutoMapper`. Add it as tag as well. You will certainly find someone helpful that will guide you on how to configure it with your need :)

Comment: here is a link to a tutorial, maybe it will help : https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/automapper-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your `base64` conversion logic to your `Automapper` configuration

```
cfg.CreateMap<MediaDto, MediaModelResponse>()
    .ForMember(i => i.Content, cfg => cfg.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
    {
        string metaInfo = string.Format("Data: {0}; Charset: {1}", src.Type, Encoding.UTF8.WebName);
        string base64String = metaInfo + Convert.ToBase64String(src.Content);

        return base64String;
    }));
```